# How to get the actual main address use idapython when starting IDA in batch mode?

Tags: python, ida

When starting IDA in GUI mode to analyze the binary, it automatically locates and displays the actual main function code (not the entry point encapsulated by the compiler, but the main function corresponding to the source code).

My question is how to get that address in **batch mode (without GUI)** via idapython script? I don't see the relevant interface in the IDAPython documentation.

For example, `_mainCRTStartup --> ___mingw_CRTStartup --> _main` is a sequence of function calls, where `_mainCRTStartup` is the entry point of the binary, but I want to get the address of **`_main`**, can it be done?

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know the answer, it is idaapi.inf_get_main()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).